# JavaScript: IF time >= 9:30 then

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a statement that says "if time is this and less than that then".  I can use get hours and get min.  However, I'm having problems combining a time such as 9:30.

Example,

```
var now = new Date();
var hour = now.getHours();
var day = now.getDay();
var mintues = now.getMinutes();

if (day == 0 && hour >= 9 && hour <= 11 && mintues >= 30) { 
    document.write(now); 
}
```

This only if the time is less between 9:30 10.  As soon as the clock hits 10 the minutes are then < 30 and the script breaks.

Any thoughts on how to better incorporate the time function to make this theory work?

Thanks,

Comment: I've indented your code, but in it's current state it won't even get parsed. I suggest that you take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide to learn the basics.

Answer (score 8):

use `new Date().getTime()` returns milliseconds for much easier comparison. This way there is no need to check *hour, min, second, millisecond*. [Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/jruddell/nSre4/)

```
var d930 = new Date(2010, 12, 21, 9, 30, 0, 0), // today 9:30:00:000
    d931 = new Date(2010, 12, 21, 9, 31, 0, 0), // today 9:31:00:000
    t930 = d930.getTime(),
    t931 = d931.getTime();


console.log(t931 > t930);
```

This way your code can check against a static 9:30 time.

```
var time930 = new Date(2010, 12, 21, 9, 30, 0, 0).getTime(),
    sunday = 0,
    now = new Date();

if(now.getDay() == sunday && now.getTime() >= time930){
    /* do stuff */
}
```

Comment: I'm only wanting static days.  For example, every sunday.  In your example it is for a specific day of year.  How might you adjust it?

Answer (score 6):

You have a few typos and basic javascript errors.
Might wanna brush up on the basics.
[W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp)   is where I learned all I know.
It works fine if you fix them...

```
var now = new Date();
  var hour = now.getHours();
  var day = now.getDay();
  var minutes = now.getMinutes();
  if(day == 0 && hour == 9 && minutes < 30 && minutes > 10 || day == 0 && hour == 9)
      document.write('Time is between 9:10 and 9:30');
```

Think of the if statement as basic logic.
If the day is Sunday(0)
AND the hour is 9
AND the minutes are greater than 10
AND the minutes are less than 10
OR the day is Sunday(0)
AND the hour is before 9.

Comment: +1 for recommending W3Schools. Their tutorials are informative and are not as inaccurate as what everybody says they are.

Answer (score 3):

```
  var now = new Date();
  var closeTime = new Date();
  closeTime.setHours(9); closeTime.setMinutes(30);
  console.log(now, closeTime, now.getTime() >= closeTime.getTime());
```

close time is based on today, then we just change the hours and minutes to 9:30.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem to solve today, I setup a little component that returns if a place of business is open or not. Got the time by dividing the minutes by 100 then adding it to the hours. So 8:30 is represented as 8.3

```
let d = new Date()
let day = d.getDay()
let hours = d.getHours()
let minutes = d.getMinutes() / 100
let time = hours + minutes

if (day == 1) {
  if (time > 8.3 && time < 17.3) {
    setIsOpen(true)
  } else {
    setIsOpen(false)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if the hour is less than 9, true
or
if hour is 9 and minutes lt 30, true
```

so that would look like

```
if ((hour < 9) || (hour == 9 && minutes < 30))
```

Use words to figure out your logic. Symbols are just shortcuts.

Answer (score 2):

I made this solution simple and easy to read (thus easy to adjust).

```
// we need a function that makes hours and minutes a two digit number
Object.prototype.twoDigits = function () {
    return ("0" + this).slice(-2);
}

// get current date and time
let now = new Date();

// compile the current hour and minutes in the format 09:35
timeOfDay = now.getHours().twoDigits() + ':' + now.getMinutes().twoDigits();

// test if timeOfDay is within a given time frame
if ('09:30' <= timeOfDay && timeOfDay <= '11:30') {
    console.log('inside time frame');
} else {
    console.log('outside time frame');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to do a direct comparison on date objects. Choose an arbitrary year, month and day, and then incorporate your times as follows:

```
var older = new Date("1980-01-01 12:15");
var newer = new Date("1980-01-01 12:30");

if (newer > older){
    alert("Newer time is newer");

} else {
    alert ("The time is not newer");

}
```

The MDC [documentation on the Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/global_objects/date) will help with some more details. The bottom line is that if you want to compare times, you don't actually need to call any methods on the objects, and it's possible to directly compare them. The date() object can take a variety of strings to assign a new time to the returned instance, these are from the MDC documentation:

```
today = new Date();
birthday = new Date("December 17, 1995 03:24:00");
birthday = new Date(1995,11,17);
birthday = new Date(1995,11,17,3,24,0);
```

As you can see, it's pretty simple. Don't complicate, and have a look through the documentation :)

While we're here, here's a test using your example:

```
var base = new Date("1980-01-01 9:30");
var test = new Date("1980-01-01 9:30:01");

if (test >= base){
    alert("test time is newer or equal to base time");

} else {
    alert ("test time is older than 9.30");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var now = new Date(); 
var hour = now.getHours(); 
var mintues = now.getMinutes();

if(
        (hour*60 + mintues) > 570 && 
        hour <= 11
    )
{
    document.write(now); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite fully understand your question but hope this helps.

```
c = new Date();
nhour  = c.getHours();
nmin   = c.getMinutes();

if(nmin <= 9) {
    nmin = "0" + nmin;
}
if(nhour <= 9) {
    nhour = "0" + nhour;
}

newtime = nhour + "" + nmin;

if(newtime <= 0930){
    alert("It is before 9:30am or earlier");
}
```